# how to include jboss in jasper report server instead of tomcat

Tags: jasperserver, jboss6.x

i have installed jasper report server on Ubuntu os, by default it uses tomcat.
i want to include jboss  in jasper report server and exclude tomcat.
pls help...   any links in this regard would be appreciable.

Comment: Why would you like to do that? It's technically possible, but I don't think it will be an easy task. If it's for integration issues, using a *reverse proxy* or something similar will be way easier.

Answer (score 0):

JBoss 5.1 or 7.1 is supported by the Jasper Report Server WAR File Distribution, i would suggest you follow documentation:

- [Installing the WAR File Distribution](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-installation-guide-community-edition/v60/installing-war)